# Taylor expansion of sin(x)

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-series

I need to make a program for the Taylor expansion of sin(x).
I made something but I don't know if it is good. I don't know how to check it.
Could you please check it?

```
double mein_sinus (double x,long n)
{
  double p;
  double px;
  double fakto;
  double resultat;
  long i;

  for (i=0; i <= n; i++)
  {
    p = pow(-1, i);
    px = pow(x,(2*i + 1));
    fakto = faktoriel (2*i + 1);
    resultat = p * px / fakto;
  }

  return resultat;
}
```

Comment: Compare the result with the language's sin function to see if you have it correct. Or look up values in a sine table or on a pocket calculator.

Comment: Does it work? Is it bugfixing or code review you're after? If bugfixing, please state the nature of the bugs you can't find. If it's code review, your code is better suited on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: As for how to check if your function is correct, I would create unit-tests with known values, and test that your approximation is "close enough", by whatever standard you deem appropriate for your project.

Comment: The code would be ok near to 0. But would quickly fall apart. Perhaps expand around the nearest multiple of 2pi